# Do I need to share OSS libraries source code when I only use them in binary?

Tags: distribution, bsd, apache-2.0, linked-libraries, mpl

I'm working on a project where BSD, Apache v2 and MPL1.1 libraries were used.
Basically propietary code will link to these libraries to run the Program. Libraries were only used in binary form, though. No code combination.

When further distributing the Program, do i need to make the source code of those OSS libraries available in the download package?
Is telling the Licensee where he may get the Source code of such OSS, sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

Apache 2.0 and all the BSD flavors have no copyleft clause. They allow distribution without sourcecode, so it doesn't matter for them.

The [MPL Version 1.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/1.1/) only requires that you make the sourcecode for those parts available which you modified. When there are no modifications you have no obligations to convey any sourcecode.

Just make sure that your end-product includes the license texts and copyright notices which are mandated by all three licenses.

Comment: As a courtesy to your users, you might state where the libraries are to be found (is useful if they are linked dynamically, so that the user can replace with a new version).